# Bootstrap form in modal cannot resolve file

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to link my deleteview URL to the 'yes' button on my modal, however, it is not deleting and in pycharm, it is showing up as: 'cannot resolve file'. I have checked my urls and view and they all seem to be correct. Any help is much appreciated. note: I am new to bootstrap

```
{% for patient in all_patients %}
<!-- Delete Patient -->
<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="{{ patient.id }}" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{patient.id}}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="{{patient.id}}" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ patient }}?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <form action="{% url 'patients:patient-delete' patient.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you  post error log

Comment: There is no error, its just not deleting

Answer (score 1):

In button type put `type="submit"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it made no difference though :(

Comment: Then there is problem with your action url and not with bootstrap

Comment: Try putting absolute url in action, instead of relative url and see if it works.

Comment: Again, no effect. Each part of the url comes up with 'cannot resolve directory'.